# python write all utf chars in a file

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-unicode

How can I write all the characters of unicode or utf-8 in a file, one by one without space between or break?

file:

```
0123456789!"#$%&'()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

...And so on from 0-100000

```
z=""
for y in range(0, 100000):
    z+=chr(y)
open("./aa", "w").write(z)

# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 55296-57343: surrogates not allowed


for z in range(0, 100000):
    print(chr(z))

# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Comment: U+D800 through U+DFFF are reserved for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) surrogates and can't be encoded.  Skip that range.

Comment: Note: it is complex, and you do not get all chars: Unicode works by combining characters (there are classes of them), so you may need different combinations. Languages may require ligatures or position dependent. And in different languages you may get different forms of the character (e.g. Chinese and Japanese: same Unicode, two different glyphs). You can also use standard module: `unicodedata`  to get informations on how to handle better the printing (e.g. forcing not to combine characters).

Answer (score -1):

Unicode is HARD! Ugh! I'm serious, I feel your pain. Every time I think I understand it, there's more...  Ugh!

Anyway, I think the problem you're hitting is described in the following couple links ([link1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/plane) and [link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))). See the colorful picture on [link2](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Roadmap_to_Unicode_BMP.svg).

The issue is that the basic multilingual plane (BMP), which contains code-points U+0000 through U+FFFF (or 0 through 65535 or 2^0 - 1 to 2^16 - 1) only contains 55503 characters.  What gives?

Well, some code-points are saved for "private use" and some are utf-16 surrogates. I don't fully grasp what those are, but they're a pair of utf8 code-points encoded for utf16. So, they make no sense as individual characters for utf8.  In the image, the surrogates start right at your magic number of 55296 (or U+D800).

I ran your code while using utf16 and got the same error, so there's clearly some more reading to be done on the surrogate code-points.  For now, if you're only considering utf8, those regions of code-points are not valid characters, so you may want to just skip them.

Comment: If I use "encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore'" and write it in a file are the characters then saved correctly?

    for i in range(0, 100000):
    open("./aa", "w", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').write(chr(i))

Comment: Question on the edge: [ Why does Stack Exchange actually have no button for question if you can give an answer, is a question not sometimes just as helpful?
After all, you don't just learn from it when you do something right. ;) ]